# What is the "key" which changes on every route change with connected-react-router?

Tags: react-router-v4, connected-react-router

When an action for navigating to a route is triggered, an action triggers a new state where the `router.location.pathname` changes according to the browser's `history`.

Another property changes as well: `router.location.key`, to a new random string.

[image: The diff between two states, showing how key changes alongside a pathname.]

Even when the pathname itself doesn't change (clicking on a link to a page from the page itself), the `key` still updates.

[image: The diff between two states, showing how only the key changes.]

What's the purpose of the `key` property? In which situations would I want my own state to have a randomly generated `key` which updates on very action dispatch? Why is it not a number which simply increments?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`connected-react-router` simply stores the location object from `react-router` which in turn creates the location object using the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) package. In the readme of `history` the `key` property is described:

> Locations may also have the following properties:
>
> location.key - A unique string representing this location (supported in
>   createBrowserHistory and createMemoryHistory)

It is used internally (e.g. in https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/modules/createBrowserHistory.js to find locations in the current history stack) and should be treated as an implementation detail of `react-router`. I suspect a random key instead of a incrementing sequence number was simply the easiest way to implement unique ids (you don't have to store the current sequence number).

Answer (score 3):

This causes unnecessary rerender of the current route, when visited once again, because props change. One way to fix that would be to use `React.memo`, and comparing the `location.path` which stays the same. But then you will have to be careful if your component receives other props, so to include them in the comparison.

Comment: Good to see someone had the exact same conclusion I had on the exact same problem I'm having. Sad to see this seems to be a common scenario and quite hard to debug, since `react-router` has no docs whatsoever about `location.key` or this re-render issue.

Comment: I opened an [issue/discussion](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8025) with the package to follow up on this problem - it seems 5.2.1 solves it, but not for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the [React Router Docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts)

> Each location gets a unique key. This is useful for advanced cases
> like location-based scroll management, client side data caching, and
> more. Because each new location gets a unique key, you can build
> abstractions that store information in a plain object, new Map(), or
> even locationStorage.