# React route: how to obtain the current route key from the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Say, I have the following wrapper:

```
<Switch>
<Route path={`/app/list`} component={ListPage} key="list"/>
<Route path={`/app/view`} component={EditPage} key="view"/>
<Route path={`/app/edit`} component={EditPage} key="edit"/>
<Route path={`/app/new`} component={EditPage} key="new"/>
 </Switch>
```

When I load the corresponding component, say ListPage, I want to be able to get the key of the current route, in this case, it would be "list".

If I check *this.props.match*, I have only *isExact*, *params*, *path*, *url* but not the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the `key` property because you just provide the component that you want to get rendered by the Router to the `Route` component and this way you cannot specify what props your component will accept except the default ones - match, location, history. You can read more about it [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

You can use the [render](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop in order to specify how to render the component by providing a render function and this way you can specify the props that your component will accept for example - `key`. The function will have all the default props provided by the router and you can just spread them as props on your component.

**Since key and ref are reserved props in React and they are not passed to the component, I've renamed the key prop to keyName. More info can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)**.

It will look like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/app/list" render={(props) => <ListPage {...props} keyName="list"/>} />
  <Route path="/app/view" render={(props) => <EditPage {...props} keyName="list"/>}/>
  <Route path="/app/edit" render={(props) => <EditPage {...props} keyName="edit"/>} />
  <Route path="/app/new" render={(props) => <EditPage {...props} keyName="new" />}/>
</Switch>
```

and you will be able to access the key by using `props.key` inside the component that is rendered.

Of course it would be better to extract the render function into a function called `renderWithKey` or something in order remove the duplication so the code to be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, it works only if the parameter name is not "key" as @MedetTleukabiluly mentioned.

Comment: You are welcome. I forgot that key was reserved so I will rename it.

Answer (score 1):

It's reserved property used in react or [react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249529/2308005) internally

If you want to get `list` use different property. `ref, key` are reserved

Comment: But how I would pass any other property? If I just add it into the route object, it's not working.